# Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync not working in Outlook for Office 365

Tags: office365, outlook-addin, office-js

I have a sign in button in my add-in that opens the microsoft oauth and this is achieved using the displayDialogAsync. I tried first in outlook web app (https://outlook.live.com) and it is working properly there, that is, it opens the dialog for sign in. But then I tried the same in the desktop client but when I click the sign in button nothing happens.

```
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(fullUrl,
        { height: 40, width: 40 }, function (result) {
            _dlg = result.value;
            _dlg.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, processMessage);
        });
```

Comment: were you able to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your callback needs to check `result.error.code` and `result.error.message`. Once you know what the error is, you can start troubleshooting. Here's an example.

```
var dialog;
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync('https://myDomain/myDialog.html',
   function (asyncResult) {
       if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
            showNotification(asyncResult.error.code = ": " + asyncResult.error.message);
       } else {
            dialog = asyncResult.value;
            dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, processMessage);
      }
});
```

I recommend you also read [Dialog API | Handle errors and events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins#handle-errors-and-events).